# Acessesing Nested Objects in React render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Not sure why I'm getting `TypeError: project.Item is not a function`error when I try to access an object inside of an array returned on my GET request.
This is how my code looks. The weird thing about this is that sometimes I get no error with this exact same code.

```
   const getProjects = async() => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  let response;

    try {
        response = await fetch (`${APIlink}/projects/`+ props.match.params.project_uid, requestOptions)
    } catch (err) {
        return;
    }
    const result = await response.json();
    setproject(result);
  }
  console.warn("props", props);
  console.log(project);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
  }, []);


  return (<div>
      <Header />
      <img src={logo}/>
  <h1>Project Title</h1>
    <Row style = {{display: "flex"}}><Col xs="6">{project.Item.profName}</Col>
                 <Col xs="6">{project.Item.dept}</Col>
    </Row>
    <Row style = {{display: "flex"}}><Col xs="6">{project.Item.duration} months</Col>
                 <Col xs="6">INR {project.Item.stipend}</Col>
    </Row>
    <Row style = {{displey: "flex"}}><Col xs="6">{project.Item.totalSlots}</Col>
                 <Col xs="6">Start Date</Col>
    </Row>
    {project.Item.description}
    <br></br>
    {project.Item.responsibilities}
    <br></br>
    

  </div>);
```

The following object is returned when I make a `GET` request to get the details of a particular Project

```
{
  "Item": {
    "project-uid": "e50ffdfaad1c4de31d6ad5e82d789c6a",
    "responsibilities": "he standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham",
    "preReq": "Fourth year",
    "addDetails": "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham",
    "dept": "mechanical",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "duration": "12",
    "totalSlots": "5",
    "stipend": "10000",
    "profName": "Dr. Aaron Sorkin",
    "user-uid": "7e7199247de1125a6dc1518dd78ba554"
  }
}
```

Comment: `Item.map` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you show. I don't think the error is coming from this part. But otherwise, if you do use `Item.map` anywhere, the issue is that it's an object, not an array.

Comment: I've edited my question, the error is `project.Item`

Comment: you should add a condition to your return to check if project is initialised before rendering
like return project && (<div> ...)

Comment: Thanks It worked! Can you explain the reason behind it?

Comment: project && ( ... ) will still fail if the initialState of the project is an { } .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect will get called after the component is mounted . So if your initial state of project is null or {} . you will get an error . You can add an additional state called loading which you can set to false once the API call is successful . Adding a loading state is a good practice when making api calls . So that we can render a loader in the future which is a good UX .

```
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);

const getProjects = async() => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
 
  let response;

    try {
        response = await fetch (`${APIlink}/projects/`+ props.match.params.project_uid, requestOptions)
    } catch (err) {
        return;
    } finally{
      setLoading(false);
     }
    const result = await response.json();
    setproject(result);
  }
  console.warn("props", props);
  console.log(project);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
  }, []);

  if(loading)
    return <h1> Fetching Data ...</h1>

  return (<div>
      <Header />
      <img src={logo}/>
  <h1>Project Title</h1>
    <Row style = {{display: "flex"}}><Col xs="6">{project?.Item?.profName || ''}</Col>
                 <Col xs="6">{project?.Item?.dept || ''}</Col>
    </Row>
    <Row style = {{display: "flex"}}><Col xs="6">{project?.Item?.duration || ''} months</Col>
                 <Col xs="6">INR {project?.Item?.stipend || ''}</Col>
    </Row>
    <Row style = {{displey: "flex"}}><Col xs="6">{project?.Item?.totalSlots || ''}</Col>
                 <Col xs="6">Start Date</Col>
    </Row>
    {project?.Item?.description || ''}
    <br></br>
    {project?.Item?.responsibilities || ''}
    <br></br>
    

  </div>);
```

Comment: Edited the answer to use optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thank you! I will design a loading component too :)